# Filling a fixed-width grid with items & consistent spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to achieve this with minimal css/js hopefully:

[image: http://i847.photobucket.com/albums/ab39/twilson90/Symbol2_zps04edc281.png]

I have a space that needs to be filled with squares with the same dimensions.
In this particular example, I have a 270px width space that needs to contain multiple 60px width boxes

I can't use margin-right/bottom, and the boxes have to fit **perfectly**.

How do I go about this?

Comment: this site has been created to help you with your existing code...

Comment: This is super easy with zen grids or bootstrap. http://zengrids.com

Comment: What else is there that you cannot use except `margin` properties? (An HTML table maybe? The most obvious approach really, though not everyone’s favorite.) The restriction sounds odd and suggests that there is something involved that is not described in the question. The problem looks almost trivial unless it is complicated by strange restrictions.

Comment: I've got maybe 10 items, maybe 15, maybe 20 etc. I figured if I use margin properties (or iow basic css) there's no way of telling if a particular item is touching a border. Any item touching the bottom or right border needs to have the corresponding property 0px, and when it's potentially 50 items in a grid that's a lot of items that need special treatment.
I just figured there's a simpler way that more experienced coders could tell me about.

Comment: Using your example, would you always have a multiple of four boxes? If you didn't what would be the expected behavior for the last row of boxes? If the last row only had two boxes should those boxes expand to fill the whole bottom row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution for a 270px wide box that is filled with 60px wide boxes. The bottom row of boxes expand to fill the row and be *perfect*. Adjust the margins and widths to fit your situation.

Note that my HTML contains 4 tables to provide a visual example. You would obviously only use one table.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 270px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td {
  float: left;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Remove margin on right edge and bottom edge */
.tr .td:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.tr:last-of-type .td {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* This makes the last row of boxes fill the row */
.tr:last-of-type .td:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 270px;
}
.tr:last-of-type .td:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2),
.tr:last-of-type .td:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 130px;
}
.tr:last-of-type .td:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3),
.tr:last-of-type .td:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2),
.tr:last-of-type .td:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 83.333333px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">1</div>
    <div class="td">2</div>
    <div class="td">3</div>
    <div class="td">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">5</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">7</div>
    <div class="td">8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">1</div>
    <div class="td">2</div>
    <div class="td">3</div>
    <div class="td">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">5</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">7</div>
    <div class="td">8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">1</div>
    <div class="td">2</div>
    <div class="td">3</div>
    <div class="td">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">5</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">7</div>
    <div class="td">8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">10</div>
    <div class="td">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">1</div>
    <div class="td">2</div>
    <div class="td">3</div>
    <div class="td">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">5</div>
    <div class="td">6</div>
    <div class="td">7</div>
    <div class="td">8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">9</div>
    <div class="td">10</div>
    <div class="td">11</div>
    <div class="td">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does the trick! However I think I found my answer elsewhere in the aforementioned Griddle. This is still very helpful though, thanks :)